# Questions related to economic development and public policies to be followed in developing countries (3rd world)

Tags: discussion, scope

I wanted to know if the questions related to challenges in economic development be posted here or on economic site or on a separate site focused on development. Questions may include international efforts and agenda (like sustainable development goals of UN) to fast track development in developing countries?

A sample question could be - challenge of automation of industry to quality employment in developing countries?

Edit - I posted the same question on economics site where they say that this is a value laden question and is unsuitable for an economic question. So, I think these type of questions are suitable for politics site.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the "challenges to automatisation" question.  I see issues with it on Politics.

The first part is political:  "Does the right to work enshrined in UDHR (art. 23) place any burden on industrialised countries to reduce automatisation and increase employment in the developing world?"

You would need to show prior research, so read the "how to [ask]" document on the help section.

The second part is more purely economic "Has automatisation increased disparities between the developed and less developed countries".  That aspect of the question is different and not on topic here.  It may be on topic on Economics. Perhaps phrased as "What evidence is there that automatisation has increased disparities..."  You could demonstrate prior research by showing that a correlation exists, or listing articles that you have read.

Make sure that your question is specific to the aspects in the articles that you don't understand.

Comment: here is the [ask] document